# auto collect information in sub_modules when import in python?

Tags: python, python-module

Suppose I have below python file structure:

```
\function_group
     |-__init__.py
     |-sub_function1
     |----|__init__.py
     |----|sub_sub_func1.py
     |----|sub_sub_func2.py
     |----|sub_sub_func3.py 
     |-sub_function2
     |----|__init__.py
     |----|sub_sub_func1.py
     |----|sub_sub_func2.py
     |----|sub_sub_func3.py
```

In each `sub_sub_funcX.py` there's a list functions will collect all function name in `sub_sub_funcX.py` itself,

```
# sub_sub_funcX.py  
# and each sub_sub_funcX.py file has similiar code

import inspect 
functions = inspect.getmembers(self?, inspect.isfunction)   # how to write the "self" here

def bar(x, y):
    return x * y

def bar1(x, y):
    return x + y
```

My questions are

1. on the above code marked `"# how"` , what is the right expression for point self? Should it be a `"sub_sub_funcX"`?
2. how I can get a full list of all those [functions] when import the top module `function_group`? I means is it possible each sub_function modules can report to the top it's function list in some how when import?
3. is there a way I can easy extend modules without adding housekeeping code in `__init__` just an easy to hook and easy to remove? for example, I change the structure like this later:

```
\function_group
     |-__init__.py
     |-sub_function1
     |----|__init__.py
     |----|sub_sub_func1.py
     |----|sub_sub_func2.py
     |----|sub_sub_func3.py 
     |-sub_function2
     |----|__init__.py
     |----|sub_sub_func1.py
     |----|sub_sub_func2.py
     |----|sub_sub_func3.py 
     |----|sub_sub_func4.py            # new added
     |-sub_function3                   # new added    
     |----|__init__.py                 # new added
     |----|sub_sub_func1.py            # new added

     |----|sub_sub_sub_function_31     # new sub added    
     |--------|__init__.py             # new added
     |--------|sub_sub_sub_sub_func1.py# new added
```

Comment: -1: Why not use sphinx `..autodoc` feature?  Wouldn't that be simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You need

```
import inspect
import sys
inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isfunction)
```

2: The best answer I can think of is to import the submodules, and inspect them in the top-level.

1. No, the onus is on the top-level package (the one which is imported) to do what it needs to do. You can't import the top package and expect the sub-packages to do their thing, unless they're imported in the top-package. And since you don't want to modify your top-level **init**.py, that's not going to happen.

Can you tell us exactly what you're trying to do with those functions? I'm getting the feeling that there *has* to be a better way than this much introspection.

Comment: Thanks sykora, to explain my problem as simple, it is a some kind of manual "filter algorithm". For example, I've got one of number list from some device say [1234567] and the input source for it is [1,2,4], what is the relaionship for them? `f(1,2,4) = 1234567`? I use dropdown way (fliter), man kind put the possible algorithm let functions(combinations) to test the possibllity of known algorithm `f'(1234567) = [1,2,4]`, that's why I need hookable functions here. and why not genetic algorithm? because I have too few output samples. and, it is not for pwd crack:-)

Comment: and, do you think I can define a common inspect function then I can invoke it on top level when import? then it will invoke same name/purpose function defined in it's sub module?